# Django - a directory in urls.py

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

Excuse me for this stupid question, but I added the directory `/home/alex/Desktop/project/media/proforma/` in `urls.py`:

```
url(r'^/home/alex/Desktop/project/media/proforma/', "home.views.index")
```

`/home/...`  is a directory for photos and pdf files.

Comment: What were you hoping would happen? What actually did happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably looking something like this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/

see MEDIA_ROOT and STATIC_ROOT

```
MEDIA_ROOT
Default: '' (Empty string)
```

Absolute path to the directory that holds media for this installation, used for managing stored files.

Example: "/var/www/example.com/media/"

See also MEDIA_URL.

```
MEDIA_URL
Default: '' (Empty string)
```

URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT, used for managing stored files.

```
Example: "http://media.example.com/"
```

Comment: Please learn about formatting code (and other parts of your posts) here.

Comment: I thought I didn't need no formatting because there is no code here. I will be careful in future.

Comment: There is code here - strings and identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest working through the "[Writing your first app with Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/)" tutorial from the Django website before trying to do much else.

Specifically, [part 3 of the tutorial covers urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial03/#design-your-urls), and explains that it's a way of linking up your application URLs (like `http://localhost/foo/bar`) to your view functions.